# python - Convolution of 3d array with 2d kernel for each channel separately

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I have a matrix of size `[c, n, m]` where `c` is a number of channels; `n` and `m` are width and height. In the particular example I have a matrix that has 1000 channels. I want to make a convolution with a kernel of the size `a x a` for each channel separately. In my example the kernel size is `3 x 3`. Is there any function in `scipy` or `numpy` that does that kind of operation without iterating through the channels with a loop?

I found `scipy.ndimage.convolve` function but I think that I can not apply that function on this problem without using a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Treat your matrix as an image and use opencv. Change the shape of your array to be [height, width, num_channels]. Then run filter2D (convolution function for images) in opencv.

```
image = cv2.imread("some_image.jpg")
image.shape # (height, width, 3) # 3 is 3 channels for Red, Green, Blue
kernel = np.ones((3,3)) / 9.
image_blurred = cv2.filter2D(image, cv2.CV_64F, kernel) # will apply the kernel for each channel. You can have more than 3 channels.
```

Answer (score 14):

I think you just need to make you kernel three-dimensional. Something like this ought to work:

```
kernel = kernel[:, :, None]
```

If `scipy.ndimage.convolve` doesn't work for 3D arrays, you could try `scipy.signal.convolve`.

Comment: great suggestion if you are trying to stay away from opencv

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Doesn't make things more complicated... Thanks a lot!